# Setting the Datepicker in IOS to pick only the Month and Year

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Is there any way possible to set a `UIDatePicker` in XCode-Interface Builder to just use the rollers of the "month" and "year" **without** the "day"? I've tried checking the file properties in the IB yet failed to find a solution for my problem...

Comment: You need to change the mode of date picker to "date" instead of date and time.

Comment: @Abdul Rehman Butt , it is no use, it show year-month-day. we just want to show year and month.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your question mentions `date` and `year` so I it seemed like `UIDatePickerModeDate` would suffice but as you are looking for `month` and `year` which is not an available option. I suggest you consider using a two component `UIPickerView` object.

**Original Answer**

You can do this by changing the `Mode` property under `Date Picker` to `Date` in the `Attributes Inspector` in the right bar ( Cmd + Option + 4 ). You can also do this programmatically,

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, but this mode shows the "day" roller as well... I would like to only display the Month and Year.

Comment: UIDatePickerModeDate - Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)

Comment: @PaulJohnParreno Hello, Have You Found solution on How to show only Year or Month ?

Comment: Its in UIKIt but not needed in swift

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is possible using the standard UIDatePicker. If you have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) it makes it clear that only four modes are available:

- UIDatePickerModeTime,
- UIDatePickerModeDate,
- UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
- UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

You may have to create your own.

Answer (score 3):

Just go with `datePicker.datePickerMode = .init(rawValue: 4269)`

[image: Demo]

Comment: Any info on this magic value of 4269? And what results is returned? Is it midnight on the 1st of the selected month and year?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is restrict the range of dates, that can be used for input using the [properties maximumDate and minimumDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006806-CH3-SW7)

This has the added benefit of being automatically localized. i.e. the order of month and day is correct.