# iOS swift How to create .p8 file?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I am working with [Pushy](https://pushy.me/) Notification where I need to register with the p8 file. So how can I create that p8 file from developer account?[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/

Comment: Hopefully your customers aren't offended by all that pushing.

Answer (score 25):

## May 2021 - The `p8`

The issue that I had was I couldn't find the way to create the **`.p8`** file and all methods gave me **`.cer`** file instead.

1. Head to your [Apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/add)
2. Go to the **keys** section and click on the plus button (or [click here](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/add)):

> ⚠️ It is very important to select the `keys` section and **NOT** the `certificate` or `identifiers`. otherwise you will get the `.cer` file at last ‍♂️

[image: Keys section]

3. Select the Apple push notification service:
   [image: Options]

> ⚠️ Note that since it is very powerful certificate, it is very limited and you  can not have much of these. So if you already created one, you will face something like this image and you should use that file or just revoke the old one.

4. Download the`.p8` file and secure it somewhere.

Comment: Don't understand why it is not so clear in Apple's docs.

Comment: I invite you to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77774474/5623035) then @Johan

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

**Generate an APNs Auth Key**

Open the APNs Auth Key page in your Developer Center and click the + button to create a new [APNs Auth Key](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/key).

[image]

In the next page, select Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production) and click Continue at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Apple will then generate a `.p8` key file containing your APNs Auth Key.

[image]

Download the `.p8` key file to your computer and save it for later. Also, be sure to write down the Key ID somewhere, as you'll need it later when connecting to APNs.

**Send Push Notifications**

Ref: [APNS (Configure push notifications)](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devcdfbb56a3?sub=deve86584d6a)

> **Important:** Save a back up of your key in a secure place. It will not be presented again and cannot be retrieved later.

Comment: Thanks for the updated. The APNs and auth key option doesn't appear in my developer account. Is there any special requirement for that?

Comment: @KushalManiyar - It can be generated once and won't be visible (removes APNS Auth key options) again. Here is reference to your query (http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev11b059073?sub=dev1eb5dfe65). If you have generated it previously, then it won't be visible to you again.

Comment: Is it possible to revoke the key and generate new one? In my account it shows, it has exceeded the limits. I want to revoke it and generate a new one. Is this possible? Also will this affect existing apps?

Comment: @yaali - Raise a new question with full description of your problem, I'll surely help you to find out solution to your problem, with valid evidence

Comment: @Krunal I have tried to configure Apple APN with Firebase FCM, but I keep getting an error. Could you please help me with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292269

Comment: How do you recommend storing the .p8 file? I assume you don't want it just sitting there plaintext

Answer (score 2):

For the new current Apple Developer site these are the steps:

Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Keys > Click "+" > Check Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)

Choose a name, then register it. It will give you an option to download the p8 file.

Answer (score 1):

First login [Apple developer a/c](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1). Go to Keys option, click **+** button

[image]

Than on next page, enter valid **Name**, check Push notification option and click, click continue, click download button, It will download .p8 file.