# Firebase p8: Invalid APN Certificate. Check the certificate in Settings

Tags: swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully registered with APN and I received the token ID. The problem is that when I send a notification from Firebase console, I get error

> Invalid APN Certificate. Check the certificate in Settings

This is the steps I followed in order to assign the .p8 APN certificate to Firebase. I am testing the app on an Iphone device. 
What am I doing wrong?

- created new key at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/
- downloaded the p8 file
- got the Team ID from  https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/
- uploaded the .p8 file in firebase console under Settings/cloud messaging
- in my .xcworspace under Targets/Capabilities/Push Notifications : ON
- myproject.entitlements file contains APS Environment  String  development.
- **NOTE:** In developer.apple.com, under APP IDs, if I click on myApp id and scroll down, Push Notifications  Configurable & Development show in yellow color and not green.

Some people on SO suggested I should create a new Key in developer.apple.com. I did it, followed same process as above, and same error.

**EDIT**

The token generated by APNs on client side looks like: `cUEPUvXjRnI:APA91bGrXvRpjXiIj0jtZkefH-wZzdFzkxauwt4Z2WbZWBSOIj-Kf3a4XqTxjTSkRfaTWLQX-Apo7LAe0SPc2spXRlM8TwhI3VsHfSOHGzF_PfMb89qzLBooEJyObGFMtiNdX-6Vv8L7`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     FIRApp.configure()

     //firInstanceIDTokenRefresh - > called when system determines that tokens need to be refreshed
     //when firInstanceIDTokenRefresh is called, our method is called too self.tokenRefreshNotification:
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

     //obtain the user’s permission to show any kind of notification
     registerForPushNotifications()
   return true

 }//end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions


 //obtain the user’s permission to show any kind of notification
 func registerForPushNotifications() {

     // iOS 10 support
     if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

            guard granted else {return}
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }

    }
        // iOS 9 support
    else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
        // iOS 8 support
    else if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
        // iOS 7 support
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
}//end of registerForPushNotifications()



   //if user decliens permission when we request authorization to show notification
  func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
         print("settings.authorizationStatus is \(settings.authorizationStatus)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {return}
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
 }



   func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
  }


 func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refereshToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("instance ID token is \(refereshToken)")

    connectToFcm()
 }


  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil  {
            print("unable to connect to FCM")
        }else {
            print("connected to FCM")
        }
     }
   }

 }//end of AppDelegate
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The bundle id in firebase app was wrongly typed, hence the reason why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to you missing the step of creating a Provisioning profile. Reference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs?authuser=0

Comment: Hmm, it may have changed but "provisioning" isn't included in that website anymore & I don't think is required for push notifications.