# How to remove Key from apple developer account?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to set up Firebase cloud messaging with APN using the p.8 file you download from developer.apple.com, but I have not been successful.
 [Firebase p8: Invalid APN Certificate. Check the certificate in Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292269)

Others here on SO, suggested I should create a new key in developer.apple.com account. I created 2 keys, nothing works.
 Now if I try to create a new key, i get error:

> You have already reached the maximum allowed number of Keys for this
>   service

If you go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/, there is a +  button to add a new key, but there is **no way to delete/revoke a key once create.**
I don't see any control that would enable one to perform such action.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are admin of this account then click on key you will see this option like attached screenshot.

[image]