# Push certificate revoked or expired?

Tags: ios, push-notification

We've used push notifications for the occasional status update (to all users) in our app for a couple of years. Today, we wanted to send another, but nothing happened. When inspecting the certificate, it says it expired november 2nd. Great.
When I go into the developer portal and "Certificates - All", I don't find my certificate anywhere. If I open the AppID to my app, it says "Push Notifications • Configurable", as if it was never configured. Is this correct? I would think it should say "Expired" instead of Configurable, and that the certificate would still exist under "Certificates"?
Is this right, or could it be that someone revoked/deleted my Certificate?

So, my only option now is to click "Configure" push notification in my app's AppID, I guess. 
If I remember correctly, it is possible to make this work with existing installed apps (without having to release/update the app), if I create a new certificate the correct way, right? How did that work?
If I click "Configure" and "Create Certificate", I get to the usual "create a CSR then upload it, then download the cert". Is it correct that if I use the same CSR as we used the previous time we created this certificate, get my new certificate, then give it to my server, I will be able to send notifications to existing devices?

Comment: looks like your certificate is revoked by someone

Comment: even if you create new certificate with new CSR... and provide it to your server. you can still send notifications.... While compile OR build time, it dont depends on any existing certificate. So dont worry about it. go, create new one, send it to server, and start sending push notifications

Comment: You should be fine, but in any event you have no other option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **P8** certificate for this type of an expiry issue. Because P8 certificate is a one time certificate and it has no expiry time. [Here you can find about the P8 certificatr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631803/ios-swift-how-to-create-p8-file)