# iOS App Not Receiving Push Notifications Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase since ever, but today I was implementing push notifications to a new project, but it's not receiving notifications from `FB Console` at all.

FCM Token is generated successfully.

APNs Key is uploaded

FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled is set to NO

GoogleService-Info is integrated

I'm Using the following code inside AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    
    Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
      } else if let token = token {
        print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
    
      }
    }
```

Messaging Delegate

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
    _ = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    completionHandler([.alert , .badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    _ = response.notification.request.content.userInfo


    completionHandler()
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

    
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
}
```

**NOTE** The following output appears when launching the app if it's gonna help

> APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID
> 'XXXXXXXX'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered
> over APNS.Be sure to re-retr

**Thanks**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID - React Native Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246620/apns-device-token-not-set-before-retrieving-fcm-token-for-sender-id-react-nati)

Comment: @MikhailVasilev No I have tried it before, my phone is connected to the internet and restarted my machine

Comment: Did you grant access to push notifications in your phone?

Comment: @MikhailVasilev Yes sure