# APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID ''. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delievered over APNS. - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to enable push notifications using firebase and this is the [document](https://iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/push-notifications-firebase-swift-5) I referred. I followed everything till the end of step 4.

This is my **PushNotificationManager.swift** file

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseMessaging
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseCore

class PushNotificationManager: NSObject, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    let userID: String
    init(userID: String) {
        self.userID = userID
        super.init()
    }
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
         
            
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded()
    }
    func updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded() {
        if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
            let usersRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users_table").document(userID)
            usersRef.setData(["fcmToken": token], merge: true)
            print(token)
        }
    }
//    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
//        print(remoteMessage.appData)
//    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded()
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(response)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Registered for Apple Remote Notifications")
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
    }
    
}
```

**This is the AppDelegate.m**

```
mport UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseMessaging

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let pushManager = PushNotificationManager(userID: "currently_logged_in_user_id")
        pushManager.registerForPushNotifications()
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
           }
          
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    
}
```

Even though I am getting the FCM token printed as per the print statement in PushNotificationManager.swift. However I am getting the following in the console

***APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID 'XXXXXXXXX'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.***

I have tried all the solutions mentioned on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246620/apns-device-token-not-set-before-retrieving-fcm-token-for-sender-id-react-nati) however I am not able to get past the error. Can someone tell me what I could be missing.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with generating the APNs token. Could you check if you uploaded a valid APNs cert? Try printing the APNs token to see if it's being generated.