# The operation can't complete. No Apns token specified before fetching the fcm token

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on react native app and had followed all the steps as per the official documentation that is required for push notification.

When I reload the app my error is disappering and I got the fcm token and its only arriving when the app is launched. I have tried everything but is being mentioned in other question of stackoverflow and google. I am using simulator for IOS app.

IOS Simulator 14 version 16.4
React native version 0.70

I have tried everything mentioned here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246620/apns-device-token-not-set-before-retrieving-fcm-token-for-sender-id-react-nati]