# Unable to Generate FCM Token in iOS React Native App

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm encountering an error while trying to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) into my iOS React Native app. When attempting to fetch the FCM token, I'm receiving the following error message:

The operation couldn’t be completed. No APNS token specified before fetching FCM Token

This is the code snippet i am using , I have done all the configuration for firebase iOS push notification. Issue is happening randomly in somecase token is getting generated and in some case i am getting below error.

```
async function GetFCMToken() {
      let fcmtoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmtoken');
       console.log(fcmtoken, 'old token');
      if (!fcmtoken) {
        try {
      const fcmtoken = await messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmtoken) {
        console.log(fcmtoken, 'new token');
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmtoken', fcmtoken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'error in fcmtoken');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69316428/10006183