# Flutter - apns device token not set before retrieving fcm token

Tags: flutter

Can someone guide me am having and error on my real device on IOS am using iphone 12

**`8.11.0 - [firebase/messaging][i-fcm002022] apns device token not set before retrieving fcm token`**

Even though check it twice again and again for the steps on appStore key,identifiers, etc.. then in xcode adding capability and so fort. But still have the error am having right now and don't know where to start looking for solution I've been searching for answers but no luck.

really thanks if you can help me on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ask for permission

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();
```

also add the Push Notification capability in the Signing & Capabilities tab of your project target in Xcode

Comment: I already set that at first also and same with in the Xcode and select ALL tab but still not resolve

Comment: have you add p8 file in firebase ?
You need to connect the p8 key to your firebase

Link to create a p8 key https://stackoverflow.com/a/67533665/13033024

Comment: Also enable backgroundmode from signing & capabilities tab and select
1.background fetch
and
2.Remote Notification

Comment: @ArbiterChil are you also having same problem as me? @ 
Ashutosh singh as you said i also already done that part which is quite doubtful for not working.

Comment: yeah am actually stuck on this part also

Comment: @B-Calv are you testing push notfication in real device if not then try in real device

Comment: yes am using my real device on IOS iphone still this log error still persists to show no matter wat i do clean get then pod install still same delete pod.lock to refresh things still not been solve

Comment: can you share your pubsepec.yml file and output of flutter doctor -v command

Comment: this is solved my problem.